# C++ why int rvalue reference changed in this example?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int&& a(int&& b) {
    cout << b << endl; //output 5
    return std::move(b);
}

string&& d(string&& e) {
    cout << e << endl; //output abc
    return std::move(e);
}
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int&& b = a(5);
    cout << b<< endl; // output 0
    string&& f = d("abc");
    cout << f << endl; //output abc
    return 0;
}
```

The function a should return an rvalue reference to 5.
Why is value of b changed after the move? while the string f is unchanged?

Comment: On `int&& b = a(5);`, `b` ends up as a **dangling reference** to a temp `int` that no longer exists once the `;` is reached, thus the following `cout << b<< endl;` is **undefined behavior**. Same with `string&& f = d("abc"); cout << f << endl;`

Comment: Rvalue references bind to things that are supposed to be short-lived. Keeping them around longer goes against their purpose.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't get the case of "abc" vs 5, doesn't both value live in the main scope?

Comment: If you have a refernce to `D` you must have `D` before a refrence to it. If `D` is temporary then the reference points to... what? Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @lostdong12 no, they are both creating temporary variables for the references to bind to. A temporary lives only until the statement that created it is finished.

Comment: Extending the lifetime of a temporary is not transitive through a function call.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am using. C++14 (gcc 8.3) on https://ideone.com/.

Comment: @NathanOliver https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary "*- a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call: if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh wow.  I was reading the code completely wrong.  Not sure how, but yeah, I definitly was thinking the code was doing `int&& b  = int(5)`, not `int&& b  = a(5)`

Comment: Why did string f live after the end of the full expression? is it just lucky good undefined behavior? @NathanOliver The other compiler also output what I thought was right.

Comment: @lostdong12 That's undefined behavior for you.  Sometimes, you get what you expect, which makes it all the more dangerous.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That was really helpful to know that function call terminates the life of the temporary bound. Does it also apply to constructors?

Comment: why would the c++ compilers allow these dangerous dangling rvalue reference, is there any case where that is permissible?

Comment: @lostdong12 "*Does it also apply to constructors?*" - what do you mean? "*why would the c++ compilers allow these dangerous dangling rvalue reference*" - C++ allows a lot of things that you can shoot yourself in the foot with. It can't hold your hand for everything, some things you just need to be wise enough to know how to be careful with them.

Comment: @lostdong12 It isn't that the language allows it. It's that the language doesn't require the compiler to detect these kinds of errors. Doing so would put an unnecessary burden on compiler implementers. It isn't easy to know if a reference will be valid, in some cases it my not be possible to know at compile time. C++ relies heavily on users being careful and knowing the rules.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I meant for example, string&& f = string("abc");. It fits the description of a function call, Is the behavior here undefined as well? At least I was hoping it would not compile int&& b = a(5); as cppreference already points out "a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call: if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference."

Comment: @lostdong12, In `string&& f = string("abc");`, the temporary is `string("abc")`, so it's not being passed through a function. The `"abc"` wouldn't live past this statement (except it does due to a special rule that string literals live for the entire program), but the temporary `std::string` is created by the full `string("abc")` and doesn't even attempt to preserve a reference to its argument. In `int&& b = a(5);`, the temporary is `5`.

Comment: @lostdong12 `string&& f = string("abc");` is not a function call, it is a constructor call. It is constructing a temporary `string` object with `"abc"` as its input parameter, and then binding the reference directly to that temporary `string`. `int&& b = a(5);` is a function call. A temporary `int` with a value of `5` is created, the function's parameter is bound to that temporary, the output reference is bound to whatever the function returns, and the temporary `int` gets destroyed after the function exits.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you mean after the "end of the full expression containing that function call"? Is constructor call not a function call under this definition? From cpluplus reference, the definition of constructor is "Constructor is a special non-static member function of a class that is used to initialize objects of its class type.".

Comment: @lostdong12 "*after the end of the full expression containing that function call*" occurs "*after the function exits*", so yes. And yes, a constructor call is like a function call, as far as its parameters are concerned. In `string("abc")`, there is no temporary parameter value being created that has to be destroyed after the `string()` constructor exits, because `string` has an overloaded constructor that accepts a `const char*` as input, which `"abc"` *decays* into, so no need for a temporary (well ok, there is a temporary `const char*` itself that is being passed by value, not by reference)

Comment: thanks everyone for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Remy's answer from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary.

"- a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call: if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference."

Both temporary objects are destroyed at the end of the full expression. The behavior is totally undefined here for both the int&& and string&&.